# Why does Cordé apologise to Padmé?

Tags: star-wars, attack-of-the-clones

In Attack of the Clones, Senator Padmé Amidala comes to Coruscant to vote on a plan to create an army of the Republic. Right after the spaceship lands, it explodes. Cordé,

> (who was playing Senator Padme's decoy) dies as a result of the blast and her last words are:

"Milady, I'm so sorry. I've failed you senator". Why does she say this? Was she part of the plot to assassinate Padme?

Comment: Cordé's death exposed the fact that she was a double.

Comment: Couldn't help but be reminded of the infamous Plinkett in this question! https://youtu.be/KPt1am18lR4?t=11m19s

Comment: YES!! [How AotC should have ended](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0cxjlN9e9-c) FTW!

Comment: I thought it was just her initial, shocked, unthinking reaction. Basically it's not about what she could possibly be apologizing about specifically, it's intended to demonstrate that she cares more about Padme's security than about her own life. She's not going "argh I'm dying," she's going "I'm sorry I couldn't be of more use to you... herk (dies)." It shows her loyalty and the strength of her relationship to Padme. Or that's the idea anyway, I'm guessing :P

Comment: She didn't save Padme from the disgrace of being part of AotC's plot.

Comment: Relevant: https://youtu.be/0cxjlN9e9-c?t=4s

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Neither the script, nor the Salvatore novelization offer any detail on why she thought she failed.

Being a part of the plot seems way too outlandish to pass Occam's Razor (and would have definitely been mentioned explicitly in canon, which it wasn't). So most likely, a more mundane explanation is one of the 2:

1. She felt she failed to prevent the explosion as part of Padme's security detail. Padme wasn't hurt, but at least 6 other people were killed AFAIR, including another handmaiden.
2. Her death prevented her from continuing to be an effective decoy and thus made the Senator vulnerable.

Neither one is confirmed in canon, but both at least make plausible sense from a point of view of a dying security decoy.

---

Out of universe, that was just one more pathetic line of dialog among many. We got a script full of Anakin's creepy come-ons to Padme, can't exactly expect Shakespeare-quality replicas here.

Comment: +1 for the answer, but regarding the postscript, if we could get away with the answer "because of atrocious dialog writing", it would cover pretty much every aspect of this movie.